# calling dup2 in child process causing parent's stdin to close

Tags: c, file, pipe, fork, stdin

I am trying to write a custom shell in C that supports multiple pipes using `fork`, `dup2` and `pipe`. My approach is for `c1 | c2 | c3`, create a 2 x 2 matrix to store two pipes, fork three child processes sequentially, call `dup2` to duplicate `stdin` and `stdout` to the correct pipe then call `exec`.

The shell works fine for the following commands: `"echo foo"`, `"ls | grep something | wc"`. But for some reason when I execute a line containing only one pipe like for example `"ls | grep something"`, the shell executes this command as expected but exits without waiting to read more lines. I spent hours trying to figure out why it exists when given a line with one pipe but works fine with more than one pipe but had no luck.

Here is the code that creates the child processes and runs the commands:

```
int main()
{
    char input_line[1000];
    size_t size;
    size_t chars;

    while(fgets(input_line, sizeof(input_line), stdin))
    {
        input_line[strcspn(input_line, "\n")] = 0;
        struct PARSE_INFO* parse_info = initialize_parseInfo();
        Parse(input_line, parse_info);
        int num_commands = parse_info->num_commands;
        int num_pipes = parse_info->num_pipes;
        int pipes[num_pipes][2];
        bool piping = num_pipes > 0;

        // Piping the pipes
        for(int i = 0; i < num_pipes; i++)
            pipe(pipes[i]);

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < num_commands; i++)
        {
            struct COMMAND* command = (parse_info->commands)[i];
            int num_args = command->argnum;

            char* newargv[num_args + 2];
            create_argv(command, newargv, "/usr/bin");  

            int pid = fork();

            if(pid == 0) // Child
            {
                char* newenviron[] = { NULL };       

                if(piping)
                {
                    if(i < num_commands - 1) // Not at end of pipe so write to next pipe
                    {
                        dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                    }
                    if(i > 0)                       // Not at beginning of pipe so read from previous pipe
                    {
                        dup2(pipes[i - 1][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                        close(pipes[i -1][0]);
                    }
                }
                execve(newargv[0], newargv, newenviron);
                perror("execve");
            }
            else  // Parent
            {
                int status = 0;
                wait(&status);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested the functions called here independently and they seem to work fine so I chose not to include them to reduce clutter. I suspect that I am not closing the pipes correctly. What's puzzling me is that, if I understand this correctly, calling `dup2` in a child process should only modify the file descriptors in that process and not affect the parent process, I am not sure why it's causing `stdin` to close in the parent process.

During my debugging efforts, I tried reading some input from `stdin` at the end of the while loop by adding this code after the else block:

```
char someinput[256];
fgets(someinput, sizeof(someinput), stdin);
printf("End of loop input: %s\n");
```

The program still terminated and did not wait to read any input. I tried printing someinput and it contained the command inputed from stdin at the beginning of the loop using from first call to fgets.  Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: There's no "should" about it. One process cannot close a different process's files, no matter what the relationship may be between the processes or the files.

Comment: On the other hand, you very much should check the return values of your function calls, at least when you care whether they succeeded.

Comment: Also, since the parent creates all the pipes in advance, every child needs to close the write end of every pipe, except the one, if any, it is going to use.  For its part, the parent needs to close each write end *before* waiting on the child that's reading from that pipe.

Comment: Overall, I think this question would be much easier to answer if it were reduced to a *bona fide* [mcve].

Comment: It would probably be better to create just one pipe in each iteration of the fork/exec loop, rather than creating them all ahead of time.

Comment: The parent needs wait until after it has created all the children before calling `wait()`. Then it should call it in a loop until there are no children. Or it could just wait for the last child.